como puedo hacer para que en una lista en la cual yo ingreso dos datos, como hago yo para que aparezcan juntos, los cuales son un str y un int
def agregar_contactos():
lista_de_contactos = []
while True:
lista_de_contactos.append(input("ingrese el nombre del contacto"))
lista_de_contactos.append(int(input("ingrese el numero del contacto")))
print(lista_de_contactos)
agregar_contactos()
